# Xcode iOS - Empty Array after XML parsing

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xml-parsing

I am despairing right now.
I've an app which worked perfectly. But suddenly it stopped working for no reason.

After logging-in the app is doing a html request which sends an xml answer.
I do parse this answer and receive an array of location information (that I display on a map later on).

The app is working perfectly alright with the simulator and on any device I've got over here.
For no reason it doesn't work anymore (the xml isn't parsed correctly, so there is an empty array) when I upload the .ipa file to our company server and download it from there.

Does anyone know about the problem?
Can someone help me?

Regards
Rob

Comment: parsing is depend upon your response and how you parse. if any key from your response is changed then you won't get proper array. you must have to debug using breakpoint. show some code.

Comment: seems like the structure of the HTML changed... can you post the HTML and the code that you use for parsing?

Comment: the structure didn't change, the app is working when I directly connect the device to xcode and share it.
it just doesn't work when I archive -> ipa -> upload to server -> download and install it